# CD to a directory

Tags: python

I have below code in tes.py file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

path = '/tmp'
f_path = os.chdir( path )
f = os.getcwd()
print f
os.system('cd f')
```

I want to get into /tmp directory when I execute tes.py file. But I am getting following error.

```
[rishb@xxxxxxx ~]$ ./tes.py
/tmp
sh: line 0: cd: f: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal in python?

Comment: The error clearly shows that `f` is not found. Check if you have `f` in `/tmp`

Comment: I think you mean: `os.system('cd '+f)` ?

Comment: How about `os.chdir()` ?

Comment: You've used literal 'f' and not variable f in the last line. Try what @Leo has said.

Comment: `f` is **a variable in Python**, so if you just put it in a string sure it doesn't work. String always is a string is a string is a string.

Comment: why not just use `os.chdir` altogether?

Comment: @LeoHuckvale I tried this now os.system('cd '+f). But still pwd has not changed after executing the code. Now I am getting result as:

`[rishb@xxxxx ~]$ ./tes.py
/tmp
[rishb@chfsn1xmcdc01 ~]$ pwd
/home/oracle
[rishb@chfsn1xmcdc01 ~]$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `os.chdir`

`cd` is a bash internal command, which change cwd of the CURRENT process, `os.system` create a subprocess, and the subprocess can not change cwd of the python process

And python can't change cwd of bash who is its parent.

You can't change cwd of `bash` using any program, except bash's `source` command